# Populating simple activity with data Asynchronously in Android

Tags: android, json

### I am trying to populate data from JSON to android Activity Asynchronously

*`my JSON URL`*:: `http://54.218.73.244:7002/RestaurantTimings`

*`JSON STRUCTURE`*::

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "RestaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 12pm"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "RestaurantTime": "11pm to 9pm"
    },
    {
        "_id": 4,
        "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 5pm"
    }
]
```

---

**Here is the code that i have tried::**

- the activity have three textviews i need to populate
- I have parsed the data and stored in a collection
- But i do not know how to populate the data to the textview's

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantTimings1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantTimings2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantTimings3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/restaurantTimings3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/restaurantTimings3"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static String url1 = "http://54.218.73.244:7002/RestaurantTimings";
    private HashMap<Integer, String> TimeMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();


    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //instantiating progressDialog
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();

    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait .. ", true, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            JSONObjParser jParser=new JSONObjParser();
            JSONArray json1=jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);

            try{
                for(int i=0;i<json1.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c=json1.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item=new Item();
                    int id=c.getInt("_id");
                    String TIME=c.getString("RestaurantTime");
                    yourData.add(item);
                }

            }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            TextView TV1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.restaurantTimings1);



        }

    }



}
```

**JSONObjParser.java**

```
public class JSONObjParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONObjParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    private String Time;

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String Time) {

        this.Time=Time;
    }


}
```

---

- I have completed most of the parts of the code
- But i am having difficulty in completing `onPostExecute` method

**AnyIdeas**,

Comment: Just an observation: there's no need to call `super.onPreExecute();` and `super.onPostExecute(result);` as those methods have empty bodies on the `AsyncTask` class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to derive your activity from ListActivity rather than Activity, and call setListActivity(yourData) (It may not be necessary for you to call setContentView() because ListView takes care of that for you)

In onPostExecute you can call yourData.NotifyDataSetChanged() and that will update the screen.

However if you really do want to hard-code the application to display exactly three restaurants, you could use findViewById(R.id.restaurantTimingsN).setText([new value]) to change the contents of the TextViews..